# sql count number of exact or similar records in join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with the tables:
users, user_courses, courses and course_categories

The structure looks similar to what is shown below:

```
USERS
------------------------------------------------------------
id      username
------------------------------------------------------------
1       john
2       amy
3       sarah
4       james
5       nick

USER_COURSES
------------------------------------------------------------
user_id     course_id
------------------------------------------------------------
1            2
1            3
1            4
2            2
3            1
4            3
5            4
5            5

COURSES
------------------------------------------------------------
id,     course_category_id  course_name
------------------------------------------------------------
1       1                   english language
2       1                   english literature
3       2                   algebra
4       3                   physics
5       3                   biology

COURSE_CATEGORIES
------------------------------------------------------------
id      category_name
------------------------------------------------------------
1       language
2       mathematics
3       science
4       computing
```

I am trying to write a query that takes a user_id e.g. id 1 for John and returns results showing the number of exact courses in common (courses where the course_id match) and the number of common courses (courses where the category_id are the same)

So based on the above example database, the query should return the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
user_id | username | num_exact_courses | num_common_courses
------------------------------------------------------------
2         amy        1                   0
3         sarah      0                   1
4         james      1                   0
5         nick       1                   1
```

How would I accomplish this? Would greatly appreciate some help here. Thanks

Comment: I don't get it... Sarah whose only course_ID is 1 shares no courses with John whose courses are (2,3,4) is an exact match?  The results don't seem to match my understanding of the requirements.

Comment: I'm lost as well. Amy and John both have course_id 2 but no match.

Comment: how do you distinguish between exact courses and common courses?

Comment: @xQbert You are both correct, I have updated the question to show the correct results.

Comment: @JohnRuddell an exact course is one where the course_id is the same, a common course is one where they do not have the same IDs but belong to the same category.

Comment: Two ways to accomplish 1st 2 subselects within the main select to find matches to John.  2nd approach generate two subsets one with John one with everyone else then match on course OR category use case logic set value to 1 and sum them up...

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the reply. Would it be possible to demonstrate that  as an answer, showing the query?

Comment: John has already demonstrated the first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so basically here you have a master select that gets the rows from user_courses.. then you have to left join the other rows so that there is no filtering... group by the id and filter by a user id.. so in this case 1 for John.. i use COALESCE to change null to 0 values and that gives the final result set :)

```
SELECT 
    uc.user_id, 
    u.username, 
    COALESCE(t.num_exact, 0) as num_exact_courses, 
    COALESCE(t1.num_common, 0) as num_common_courses 
FROM user_courses uc
JOIN users u ON u.id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
(   SELECT COUNT(course_id) AS num_exact, uc.user_id
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN user_courses uc ON u.id = uc.user_id 
    WHERE uc.course_id IN
    (   SELECT course_id  -- # -- get courses where john is in
        FROM user_courses 
        WHERE user_id = 1
    ) AND uc.user_id <> 1 -- # -- but make sure its not john that has the course
    GROUP BY uc.user_id
) t ON t.user_id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_common, uc.user_id 
    FROM courses c
    JOIN user_courses uc ON uc.course_id = c.id
    WHERE course_category_id IN
    (   SELECT c.course_category_id  -- # -- get course categories that john has
        FROM courses c
        JOIN user_courses uc ON uc.course_id = c.id
        WHERE uc.user_id = 1
    )
    AND course_id NOT IN -- # -- and make sure that the other users dont have the same course as john but are in the category
    (   SELECT c.id 
        FROM courses c
        JOIN user_courses uc ON uc.course_id = c.id
        WHERE uc.user_id = 1
    )
    GROUP BY c.id
) t1 ON t1.user_id = uc.user_id
WHERE uc.user_id <> 1
GROUP BY uc.user_id;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ef29/2)

Comment: Huge thanks for this, along with the explanation, certainly filled in some gaps in my knowledge.

Comment: @ScotCalvin my pleasure! thanks for accepting it quickly! :) if you have any more questions about the sql I'll be happy to explain it more